# Cause a job failure with sql for data checks

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to action some data checks following data imports into my system, im checking that all of my key locations have inventory imported for them and if they dont i would like the job to fail (I then have reporting/alerts set up when any jobs fail)

Ive had a search around and tried a number of options - The lines commented out are what i have tried but when i set INV_CHECK variable above the count level of one of my locations the job still completed succesfully. If i run in TOAD then it will fail and present an error which is what i had wanted the job to do.

```
Declare valid_loc NUMBER;
Inv_check NUMBER;
no_inv number;

BEGIN

select param_value into Inv_check from
scpomgr.udt_systemparam where param_name = 'INV_CHECK';

select count (*) into valid_loc from
(select distinct loc
from scpomgr.inventory
where loc in ('GB01', 'FR01', 'DE01', 'IT01', 'ES01', 'IE01', 'CN01', 'JP01', 'AU01', 'US01')
having count (*) > Inv_check
group by loc);

if valid_loc
<10 THEN 

--raise_application_error(-20001,'Likely Missing Inv Records');
--raiseerror('fail',16,1);
--select 1/0 into no_inv from dual;
--THROW (51000, 'Process Is Not Finished', 1);
END IF;

END;
EXIT
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what ive missed / misunderstood?

Ive added an action into the If statement so i know its running the part after the 'Then' and if i run in TOAD it gives me an error, if i do it via 'PUTTY' which is what i use to run batch processes then it comes out as 'COMPLETE' and doesnt show any sort of failure.

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server but your syntax suggest Oracle...?

Comment: Hi Stu, yes you are correct its running on Oracle, will amend that tag now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a number of trial and error i found the below code gives me the desired result, to cause my process table / putty runs to display failed i needed to use pkg_job.fatel_error and with that i could pass an error message/code.

```
Declare
valid_loc NUMBER;
Inv_check NUMBER;
BEGIN

select param_value into Inv_check from
scpomgr.udt_systemparam where param_name = 'INV_CHECK';

select count (*) into valid_loc from
(select distinct loc
from scpomgr.inventory
where loc in ('GB01', 'FR01', 'DE01', 'IT01', 'ES01', 'IE01', 'CN01', 'JP01', 'AU01', 'US01')
group by loc
having count (*) > Inv_check
);

if valid_loc < 10 THEN 

pkg_job.fatal_error('Likely Missing Inv Records',-20001); 

END IF;

END;
/

EXIT
```

Hope this helps others or gives ideas of what to try.